# Formatting dates in koGrid using Moment.Js

Tags: knockout.js, momentjs, kogrid

I have a grid that has a JSON date field. I want to format the field using Moment.JS but can't get the `cellFormatter` nor `cellFilter` fields to work.

See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cooper/8NNAk/5/ that shows the problem.

I want to apply the formatting to the HTML / data-grid, *not* the data, for example I *don't* want to do this:

```
function viewModel(){
    myArray = ko.observableArray([
        { MyDate: moment("/Date(1355875200000+0000)/").format('DD/MM/YYYY') },
        { MyDate: moment("/Date(1355875300000+0000)/"}.format('DD/MM/YYYY')} ]);
}
```

**Update:**
This fiddle doesn't appear to be working in IE.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work because of IE blocking css and js for having mime type mismatches. For example [https://raw.github.com/timrwood/moment/1.7.2/min/moment.min.js] has a mimetype of text/plain instead of application/javascript, therefore ie blocks it. It should work fine from within your own application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with the following `cellFilter` function:

```
cellFilter: function(data) { return moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY') }
```

Here is how the full columndef looks like:

```
columnDefs: 
    [
        { field: 'MyDate', displayName: 'DateTime', 
        cellFilter: function(data) { return moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY') } }
    ]
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyf3f0q1/).

Comment: It also helps to ensure the latest version of kogrid-*.js is referenced in your project...Oops.

Comment: hi @nemesv I have this in a js view model.If I inspect the data object in chrome developer tools I can see that each row has a different value for the "Timestamp" field, however KOGrid is presenting all rows with the same value - any ideas?

Comment: @RobBowman without seeing your actual code it is quite hard to tell what could cause this. You should try to reproduce this issue in jsfiddle and ask it in a separate question.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that - I was going to create a question then ran out of time (travelling now). I will try and get it done tonight.

Comment: Just posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899396/ko-grid-repeating-value. I am trying to recreate in jsfiddle now